# UNIX: How to cut columns from the right where some not all fields are the same length

Tags: unix, awk, cut

I have a list of data and I need to cut certain characters out of certain columns.

Here is the list :

```
JCG2380 GREEN, JULIE C          JR-II BISS CPSC BS   INFO TECH  XXX/XXX-9445
JAG1936 GREEN, JOE A.           SO-I  BISS CPSC BS   INFO TECH  XXX/XXX-7993
ACG4636 GREEN, ADAM C.          JR-II BISS CPSC BS   COMP SCI   XXX/XXX-0437
SPG1696 GREEN, SEAN P.          JR-I  BISS CPSC BS   COMP SCI   XXX/XXX-2398
SEG8835 GREEN, SHAWN E.         FR-II BISS CPSC BS   COMP SCI   XXX/XXX-7149
MCGo599 GREEN, MICHAEL C.       JR-I  BISS CPSC BS   COMP SCI   XXX/XXX-OOOO
GJG1887 GREEN, GREGORY J.       SO-II BISS CPSC BS   INFO TECH  XXX/XXX-4354
NGG5479 GREEN, NICHOLAS G       JR-I  BISS CPSC BS   INFO TECH  XXX/XXX-8268
ZTG7190 GREEN, ZACHARY T.       FR-II BISS CPSC BS   INFO TECH  XXX/XXX-1298
AXG9097 GREEN, ALEXANDER        SO-I  BISS CPSC BS   INFO TECH  XXX/XXX-0313
RJG6624 GREEN, ROBERT J.        SO-II BISS CPSC BS   COMP SCI   XXX/XXX-ZOZI
MWG1990 GREEN, MATTHEW W        SO-II BISS CPSC BS   INFO TECH  XXX/XXX-0581
```

The problem here is that not all the fields are the same size. Notice how Alexander Green (3rd from the bottom) does not have a middle initial. This prevents me from using awk uniformly on each column. My solution is to cut everything on the right side of the file so that the field delimiter won't mess everything up.

So how can I use the cut command to start at the right-most column and cut back 7 columns?

Comment: Put your sample input as text so people can cut and paste, and then also show your expected output so people can test their solutions. And maybe explain better what you're trying to do --- you want to remove the last 7 characters from each line? From each field? From some fields?

Comment: I tried to paste the actual text in but the formatting got all messed up and it was almost impossible to read. Any hints how to do this? But anyways, exactly what I'm trying to do is get the first character out of the columns that start (from the top entry) with JR, BISS, CPSC, INFO. Then I need the last 4 digits from the phone numbers on the right.

Comment: It would help if you specified exactly what you are trying to do.  Probably, you can use awk and reference fields as `$(NF-n)`.  eg, `$(NF-2)` is the column third from the end.

Comment: For example, to remove the `-` from the `JR-I` values, use `awk '{gsub("-", "", $(NF-6))}1'`

Comment: @LukeDangerKozorosky - It's still not clear what the input actually looks like.  You mention there is a "field delimiter", but if there is a uniform field delimiter, then the task you've described seems trivial.  Looking at the data, it would seem that that apart from the "name-of-person" field, all the fields have a fixed number of white-space-delimited tokens, and that the fields are also delimited by white space.  If that's the case, then an awk solution might also be trivial if the requirements regarding whitespace in the output are also reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cut as your data has fixed width fields.

Here is what I got with the ocr'd text:

```
$ cut -c 33-51,73-77 input
JR-II BISS CPSC BS 9445
SO-I  BISS CPSC BS 7993
JR-II BISS CPSC BS 0437
JR-I  BISS CPSC BS 2398
FR-II BISS CPSC BS 7149
JR-I  BISS CPSC BS OOOO
SO-II BISS CPSC BS 4354
JR-I  BISS CPSC BS 8268
FR-II BISS CPSC BS 1298
SO-I  BISS CPSC BS 0313
SO-II BISS CPSC BS ZOZI
SO-II BISS CPSC BS 0581
```

and to match the requirement you wrote in a comment:

> Exactly what I'm trying to do is get the first character out of the
>   columns that start (from the top entry) with JR, BISS, CPSC, INFO.
>   Then I need the last 4 digits from the phone numbers on the right.

```
$ cut -c 32-33,38-39,43-44,48-49,64-64,73-77 input
 J B C B 9445
 S B C B 7993
 J B C B 0437
 J B C B 2398
 F B C B 7149
 J B C B OOOO
 S B C B 4354
 J B C B 8268
 F B C B 1298
 S B C B 0313
 S B C B ZOZI
 S B C B 0581
```

You'll need to adjust the ranges for your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

The following meets the requirements as I understand them, except that I've used a tab as a field separator for the output to make it easy for you to make adjustments:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} { 
   # Each line is assumed to have a variable number
   # of name fields plus 8 other tokens:
   nnames = NF-8;

   # from the right:
   tel=$NF; 
   subject2=$(NF-1); 
   subject1=$(NF-2);
   bs=$(NF-3); cpsc=$(NF-4); biss=$(NF-5); data=$(NF-6);

   name=$2;
   for (i=2; i<=nnames;i++) {name=name " " $(i+1)}

   # Adjustments
   data=substr(data,2); biss=substr(biss,2); cpsc=substr(cpsc,2); 
   subject1=substr(subject1,2)
   sub( /[^-]*-/,"", tel);

   print $1, name, data, biss, cpsc, bs, subject1 " " subject2, tel;
}'
```

The output:

```
JCG2380 GREEN, JULIE C  R-II    ISS PSC BS  NFO TECH    9445
JAG1936 GREEN, JOE A.   O-I ISS PSC BS  NFO TECH    7993
ACG4636 GREEN, ADAM C.  R-II    ISS PSC BS  OMP SCI 0437
SPG1696 GREEN, SEAN P.  R-I ISS PSC BS  OMP SCI 2398
SEG8835 GREEN, SHAWN E. R-II    ISS PSC BS  OMP SCI 7149
MCGo599 GREEN, MICHAEL C.   R-I ISS PSC BS  OMP SCI OOOO
GJG1887 GREEN, GREGORY J.   O-II    ISS PSC BS  NFO TECH    4354
NGG5479 GREEN, NICHOLAS G   R-I ISS PSC BS  NFO TECH    8268
ZTG7190 GREEN, ZACHARY T.   R-II    ISS PSC BS  NFO TECH    1298
AXG9097 GREEN, ALEXANDER    O-I ISS PSC BS  NFO TECH    0313
RJG6624 GREEN, ROBERT J.    O-II    ISS PSC BS  OMP SCI ZOZI
MWG1990 GREEN, MATTHEW W    O-II    ISS PSC BS  NFO TECH    0581
```